# WPF Application.Startup property (not StartupUri)

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, app.xaml

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.aspx) for `System.Windows.Application` lists a property called `StartupUri`. However,  [this MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948#Opening_a_Window) uses `Startup`.

Where is `Startup` defined? I couldn't find it in the MSDN documentation.

This might be obvious to some, I'm just entering into the C#/WPF world.

Comment: It took a while for me to even notice that the example didn't have the "uri" part on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Startup` is an event on the Application class. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup.aspx) for more details.